# Make popover bootstrap on element in rails 4 with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to add onclick event on an `apple` element in rails. This is coffeescript.

```
apple.on 'click', () ->
  $(this).popover('[data-content="This is the body of Popover"]');
```

How can I transform it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed the `HTML data attribute` with `JS attribute`. So the right answer is this.

```
$('#apple').on 'click', () ->
      $(this).popover({content = "This is the body of Popover"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect the element on your web page and check the console to see if there are any JS errors. I think that you should also properly reference 'apple'. For example:

```
$('#apple').on 'click', () ->
  $(this).popover('[data-content="This is the body of Popover"]');
```

I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough rep. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: No, the `apple` should stay like this because it is a variable defined above. I figured out what was the problem. I mixed the HTML data attribute with JS attribute. Eventually should be like this.
`apple.on 'click', () ->
  $(this).popover({ content: "This is the body of Popover" });`